# Webdriverio element not clickable at point?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Im currently attempting to click on a checkbox button.

DOM code of the element:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="option-1">Option 1</label>
```

I have created the following test using WebdriverIO and Mocha:

```
  it("Click on checkbox button", () => {
    browser.pause(5000);
    const clickByXpathSelector = $("//div[@id='checkboxes']//input[@value='option-1']");
    clickByXpathSelector.waitForDisplayed();
    clickByXpathSelector.scrollIntoView();
    clickByXpathSelector.click();
    expect(clickByXpathSelector.isExisting()).to.be.true;
    expect(clickByXpathSelector.isSelected()).to.be.false;
    expect(clickByXpathSelector.isDisplayed()).to.be.true;
    browser.pause(5000);
  });
```

Exception message:

```
unknown error: Element <input type="checkbox" value="option-1"> is not clickable at point (432, 220). Other element would receive the click: <p>...</p>
```

The element is clearly in view for it to be interactable and the element not housed within an iframe.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you point to the (minimal amount of) HTML that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: Make sure the element is in the view of the webpage, when script is trying to interact with the element than it might be somewhere down or on top, where you need to go by scrolling so that the element should be in view therefore, it should be clickable by script.

Comment: That error means that Selenium has located the element and attempted to click on it. When it attempted to click on it, another element got in the way (received the click)... that element was the `<p>...</p>` part of the error message. You'd have to look and see what's getting in the way. There's any number of potential issues... a popup or some other UI element that's in the way permanently that you need to dismiss or scroll out of the way, some UI element like a Loading... popup that eventually goes away on it's own, or maybe some label, etc. element that's just too big and covers the element

Comment: There's no way for us to tell without access to the page so you will have to do some more investigation and let us know what you find.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the checkbox using the javascipt? Seems to be a paragraph element overlapped the checkbox. Try to close any disclaimers or notification or cookie policies  before interacting with the elements on the page.

Comment: thanks all, I can confirm there I no popups, I have also attempted to scroll to the element prior to interacting with it, do you by change have an example JS command with the use of addCommand?

Answer (score 1):

First try to use Action class to click on element in webdriverio.
Also add some explicit waits

If still not work use below code:

```
// clicks on element using JavaScript
browser.addCommand("jsClick", function(this: ElementResult) {
  this.then((element) => {
    browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", element.value);
  });
});
```

Above code click using addCommand which is similar to selenium **JavaScriptExecutor**.

Source about addCommand:

http://webdriver.io/api/utility/addCommand.html

Comment: thanks looks like im getting the following exception when adding the above command to my wdio file; 'types' can only be used in a .ts file also how would i effectively call the method within my wdio file?